# Have a link on mobile website that bypasses the mobile redirect of a .htaccess file on a main website

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I have 2 versions for one website. A normal website and a Jquery mobile website. I run one defaultrewite.php template and pull my content from a MYSQL database.

I want to be able to put a link onto my mobile website that goes to the mainwebsite?

Everytime I access the mainwebsite from a mobile device e.g iphone,  The .htaccess file sends me to the mobilewebsite.

below is the code for my .htaccess file.

Thanks

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9-_]*)$ default-rewrite.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^http://sonae.co.za/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera   mobile|palmos|webos|symbian|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobile.sonae.co.za/ [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a line above the second `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !nomobile
```

You can then allow mobile devices to access the regular site by including this in the query string, e.g.

```
http://sonae.co.za/foo/bar?nomobile
```

This works by requiring that the string not be present in the query string

Answer (score 0):

Have the link go through a redirecter page, set a cookie called use_desktop if they click on that link:

```
$url = $_GET['redirect_url'];
setcookie('use_desktop', 1, time() + 60*60*24*30, '/');
header("Location: $url");
exit;
```

then add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie} !(^|;\ *)use_desktop=([^;\ ]+)
```

as another condition before the rewrite rule.

This will be better than the query string as once that query string is gone (i.e. they click on a link) they will be redirected back to the mobile version, this lets them continue to be on the desktop version until they click on a "use mobile link", which would go through a redirecter and remove that cookie.

Comment: Your right about the answer above yours. I got error in the PHP above saying that I cannot modify headers in lines 2 and 3 so I tried and I get same error in line 2?
$url = $_GET['http://www.sonae.co.za'];
setcookie('use_desktop', 1, time() + 60*60*24*30, '/');
echo("$url");
exit;

Comment: You have to make sure you haven't echoed anything out yet to redirect.  If you still have problems you could combine this with the other answer, link directly to the desktop version with ?use_desktop=1 or something, set a cookie in that case (so you avoid the redirect), and then do a rewrite condition for the cookie and another one for the cookie.